# HTML5 input+datalist control item selection with Selenium

Tags: java, html, angular, selenium, html-datalist

Use case is to select an item from a dropdown with help of selenium. I have tried the following but unable to achieve my goal. The input tag refers to a datalist .

```
    String baseUrl = "https://angular-cwmwke.stackblitz.io" ; 
    driver.get(baseUrl); // opens the webpage
    // Put some wait for the page to load the dropdown
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@list='id-car']")).click(); // clicks on the dropdown
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='id-car']/option[1]")).click(); // Does not works.
```

It fails and this is the exception .
*JavascriptException: javascript error: option element is not in a select*

Selenium version : 3.14.0 and
Chrome version : 78.0.3904.108

Here is the HTML ( Please ignore the option values ) :

```
<input _ngcontent-c0="" list="id-car" ng-reflect-model="[object Object]" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
<datalist _ngcontent-c0="" id="id-car">
<!--bindings={
 "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
   }-->
 <option _ngcontent-c0="" value="[object Object]" ng-reflect-value="[object Object]">Ford-GTX</option>
 <option _ngcontent-c0="" value="[object Object]" ng-reflect-value="[object Object]">Ferarri - Enzo</option>
 <option _ngcontent-c0="" value="[object Object]" ng-reflect-value="[object Object]">VW - Amarok</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: If there is a transition/animation effect on the drop down sometimes that can mess with the option click, you might try adding a `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` or a hard wait of a second or two before the option click?

Comment: I did tried with a wait but that did not helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to note initially about the `datalist` tag, this is different than a `select` in that a `select` element limits the choices to a predefined set, and a `datalist` gives *suggested* options, but can take any input. Also, the `datalist` options are usually used with the `value` attribute, so in this case (and you can test this manually too) when you click any option, the displayed value is the same ([object Object]).

That being noted, the reason you are getting an *JavascriptException: javascript error: option element is not in a select* is due to, I think, Selenium expecting `option` tags to be under a `select` element. **The `datalist` tag operates more like a regular input text box than a select, and must be treated as such when using Selenium**.

So, firstly, if you have access to that html code I would update the values to be what the text is now. It would look something like this:

```
<option _ngcontent-c0="" value="Ford-GTX" ng-reflect-value="Ford-GTX"/>
<option _ngcontent-c0="" value="Ferarri - Enzo" ng-reflect-value="Ferarri - Enzo"/>
<option _ngcontent-c0="" value="VW - Amarok" ng-reflect-value="VW - Amarok"/>
```

The Selenium code for "selecting" a certain option would then be something like this:

```
var input = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@list='id-car']"));
var option = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='id-car']/option[1]"));
var value = option.getAttribute("value");
input.clear();
input.SendKeys(value);
```

If this isn't the behavior you would like to achieve, and again you have access to the html, you might consider using a `select` element instead.

If you don't have access to the html, and really want to use the inner html text, you can simply modify the above code to reference the `innerHTML` instead of `value`:

```
var input = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@list='id-car']"));
var option = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='id-car']/option[1]"));
var text = option.getAttribute("innerHTML");
input.clear();
input.SendKeys(text);
```

Keep in mind however, that this might lead to some strange behavior upon form submit, as a true user click is displaying the `value`, and not the `text`.